# Verifty if a tree is BST or not using Haskell

Tags: haskell

Hello I am new to Haskell and trying to write a function to check if a tree is binary search tree or not .

Below is my code :-

```
 data Tree = Node Int Tree Tree   
                | Leaf Int            
      deriving (Eq,Show)

val :: Tree -> Int
val (Leaf i) = i

isBst :: Tree -> Bool
isBst (Leaf i) = True
isBst (Node x l r) = if (x >  (val l )) && (x < (val r)) then True else False
```

But I get the following error when I execute it .

```
<interactive>:10:1: Not in scope: ‘isBST’
```

Can anyone please help me fix this or help me write a method to `determine if a tree is bst or not using haskell`.

Can you also please help to `make this code exhaustive` ?

Comment: that's not all of your code.

Comment: This is a bad definition, it doesn't admit empty trees or trees with 2 integers in them.

Comment: You defined `isBst` but tried to use `isBST` (uppercase).

Comment: Side note: `if (x >  (val l )) && (x < (val r)) then True else False` is equivalent to `x >  (val l ) && x < (val r)` because boolean expressions are of type `Bool`.

Comment: I suggest a different approach: Do you already know how to check if a list is sorted? Convert your Tree into a list!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you named your function `isBst` (with a lower case `s` and `t`), but tried to use it as `isBST` (with capital `S` and `T`).

Beyond that your `val` function is not exhaustive and will cause an exception when called with a `Node` as its argument. You'll need to add a case that accepts a `Node` and returns its value.

Additionally your `isBst` function will only ever look at the root of the tree, that is it will return `True` if the value of the root is between the values of its subtrees without caring whether the subtrees themselves are sorted. To work properly it should invoke itself recursively on the subtrees.

Your function will also return `False` if the value of the node is the same as that of one of the subtrees. This doesn't matter if the tree is constructed in such a way that it will never contain duplicated, but otherwise this should be fixed.

Comment: How to make it exhaustive ?

Comment: @Newbie As sepp2k suggested above, add a definition for the `Node` case. E.g. `val (Node i _ _) = i`

Comment: n.m.'s point about the definition of the type seems important enough to justify expansion in the answer.